# How to test that the renderItem function returns a <ListItem />?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, listitem, react-native-flatlist

I'm building my app with React Native and I do my unit tests with Jest and Enzyme. How can I test my `<FlatList />`'s `renderItem()` function?

It returns a `<ListItem />` from the React-Native-Elements library.

Let me give you the example code:

```
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

export class MyList extends Component {
  const list = [
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      subtitle: 'Vice President'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
    },
    ... // more items
  ]

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      title={item.name}
      subtitle={item.subtitle}
      leftAvatar={{
        source: item.avatar_url && { uri: item.avatar_url },
        title: item.name[0]
      }}
    />
  )

  render () {
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to test the `renderItem()` function. My problem is, that `wrapper.instance().renderItem({item: item})` returns the error: `TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).renderItem(...).find is not a function`. Let me give you the code of the test that I wrote:

```
describe("component methods", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let props;
  let item;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = createTestProps();
    wrapper = shallow(<MyList {...props} />);
  });

  describe("renderItem", () => {
    describe("user", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        item = {
          name: 'Chris Jackson',
          avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
          subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
        };
      });

      it("should display the order as a <ListItem />", () => {
        expect(
          wrapper
            .instance()
            .renderItem(item)
            .find("ListItem")
        ).toHaveLength(1);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How would I have to write this test so that I can test if the function correctly renders a `<ListItem />`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test `FlatList` with [react-native-testing-library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api#render)

Here's example:

#### Components:

```
const Item = ({ name ) => <Text>{name}</Text>

class LisItem extends React.Component {
  _keyExtractor = (item: { id: string }) => item.id

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {todos && (
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.todos}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={({ item: { id, name } }) => (
              <Item
                key={id}
                name={name}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Unit testing:

```
import { render } from 'react-native-testing-library'

const mockDataTodos = [
  {
    id: 'id-1',
    name: 'Todo-1',
  },
  {
    id: 'id-2',
    name: 'Todo-2',
  },
  {
    id: 'id-3',
    name: 'Todo-3',
  },
]

describe('Testing FlatList', () => {
    test('Error component should be render when error is true', () => {
      const componentTree = render(
        <ListItem todos={mockDataTodos} />,
      )

      expect(componentTree.getAllByType(FlatList).length).toBe(1)
      expect(componentTree.getAllByType(Item).length).toBe(mockDataTodos.length)
    })
})
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Note about getAllByType `their usage is discouraged`, https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/migration-v2/#removed-functions

Comment: used 'findAllByType()' instead of getAllByType

Answer (score 8):

`renderItem()` returns a JSX element.  [JSX compiles to React.createElement() which returns an object](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects).

Therefore, the return value from `renderItem()` is just an object.

You can test that `renderItem()` creates the correct object by doing the following:

```jsx
it("should display the order as a <ListItem />", () => {
  const element = wrapper
    .instance()
    .renderItem(item);
  expect(element.type).toBe(ListItem);
  expect(element.props).toEqual({
    title: 'Chris Jackson',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    leftAvatar: {
      source: { uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg' },
      title: 'C'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a nice answer

Answer (score 4):

You can also test using the `renderProp` function.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent {...defaultProps} />);
const flatList = wrapper.find('FlatList');

const item = flatList.renderProp('renderItem')({ item: yourData });
expect(item).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure whether you've extracted some code out of a class-based component, but `renderItem` itself is a component.  I can maybe give you some test code for that and you can adapt it for your needs, assuming you imported shallow and set up your item variable:

```
describe('renderItem', () => {
   it('should display as a ListItem', () => {
       const wrapper = shallow(<renderItem item={item} />);
       expect(wrapper.find(ListItem).length).toEqual(1);
   });
});
```

There are two key things that are different from your example. One - I assume here you've imported `ListItem` into your test.  You can then pass that directly into `find`.  The second bit is you want to pass the result of finding and checking the length into `expect` and test the value of that.  Think of it is "what I want to test" (the number of `ListItem` components it can find) and then off of that you create your assertion (`toEqual(1)`).

## Additional Information to Reflect Question Edit

In your setup, I wouldn't bother to test `renderItem` directly.  Instead I'd ensure full testing of `ListItem`, and then assert things about how `MyList` renders `FlatList`.  This can be done using `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()`, or even better by asserting some things about the props given to `FlatList`.  If you are really paranoid about all of this, perhaps use `mount` instead of shallow to render it completely.

Comment: @jimkelly thank you for your help. No renderItem is not a component itself. As you can see I edited my question to reflect the changes. renderItem is a component method from `<MyList />`.

Comment: @jimkelly thank you for your additional information! Let me give you my background. I come from Python programming, which has the mantra: "explicit is better than implicit." Therefore I like to avoid toMatchSnapshot(), because in my opinion it's promotes bad practices (just implicitly checking if code has changed, versus explicitly testing code).

`mount` might be a good method to look into. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not working. You've probably misunderstood the question